# When does Shapely's "polygonize_full" detect a dangle?

Tags: python, topology, shapely, geometry-conversion

Shapely's [`polygonize_full`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize_full) operation, which merges line segments into polygons, returns four geometry collections: polygons, dangles, cuts and invalid ring lines. Dangles are defined in the documentation as "edges which have one or both ends which are not incident on another edge endpoint", while cuts are "connected at both ends but do not form part of polygon".

I assumed that the following code, which tries to polygonize a square with one edge missing, should find two dangles and one cut edge:

```
import shapely

lines = [
    ((0,0),(1,0)),
    ((1,0),(1,1)),
    ((1,1),(0,1))
]

polygons, dangles, cuts, invalids = shapely.ops.polygonize_full(lines)
```

However, the `polygons`, `dangles` and `invalids` collections are all empty, while the `cuts` collection contains the three original edges:

```
[str(cut) for cut in cuts]
# This returns ['LINESTRING (1 1, 0 1)', 'LINESTRING (1 0, 1 1)', 'LINESTRING (0 0, 1 0)']
```

When does `polygonize_full` detect a dangle? Is there a way to get the dangling edges in my test case (`0 0, 1 0` and `1 1, 0 1`) using Shapely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shapely 1.8 documentation actually used the wrong order and mixed up cuts and dangles. The values being returned are `polygons, cuts, dangles, invalids` (so `.., cuts, dangles, ..` instead of `.., dangles, cuts, ..`).

So the lines that are being printed as `cuts` in the example in the question, are actually dangling edges (matching your expectation that there should be dangles).

See https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1691#issuecomment-1366834873

Comment: Thank you for this precious information. Is it already fixed in Shapely 2.0?

Comment: Wow ... I did not know that Joris Van den Bossche is here on GIS SE :)

Comment: @swiss_knight it is already fixed in the documentation of the top-level function (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.polygonize_full.html), and will be fixed in the manual shortly in 2.0.1 (https://github.com/shapely/shapely/pull/1697)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but:
polygonize_full will not introduce (in my understanding) edges. Thus, it will not close a polygon. What it does is it generates polygons from line segments, introducing nodes where two segments intersect. Yet, they still need to be able to close the polygon with (sub)segments from the original input. In your input, the shape is a reversed "C", which is open, and forms no polygon.