# Shapely polygonize over a MultiLineString returns 0 geometry

Tags: python, shapely, polygonize

I need to polygonize a linestring feature.

To this end, I'm using the [polygonize](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize) function of [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) '1.8.5.post1' in Python 3.10.6.

```
from shapely import wkb, ops as sp_ops

wkb_str = '010500000017000000010200000002000000703D0A0FFA10434150F38E13FF153141B047E162F8104341507DAE86FE153141010200000002000000704694E6F9104341D012F201F7153141A813D0BCFA1043410022FD46F7153141010200000002000000A813D0BCFA1043410022FD46F7153141585BB117FA104341B0D85F16FF153141010200000002000000585BB117FA104341B0D85F16FF153141703D0A0FFA10434150F38E13FF153141010200000002000000B047E162F8104341507DAE86FE15314130FF2135F81043418014AE77FE15314101020000000200000030FF2135F81043418014AE77FE15314140CF66ADF8104341C03923CAF815314101020000000200000088EB5198F7104341F0B7AF43F6153141704694E6F9104341D012F201F715314101020000000200000020DBF94EF1104341D0E53F34F2153141A011A595F11043419028EDBDEE153141010200000002000000A011A595F11043419028EDBDEE15314108A392D2F1104341B069DEC1EB15314101020000000200000008A392D2F1104341B069DEC1EB153141D06F5F9FF4104341D0A370ADEC153141010200000002000000D06F5F9FF4104341D0A370ADEC153141888EE48AF410434180EB51A8ED153141010200000002000000888EE48AF410434180EB51A8ED15314140AD69B6F7104341807CD093EE15314101020000000200000040AD69B6F7104341807CD093EE153141E81DA700F810434180EB51A8EE153141010200000002000000E81DA700F810434180EB51A8EE153141986E12D3F7104341B0627FD9F0153141010200000002000000986E12D3F7104341B0627FD9F015314120DBF98EF7104341603BDF1FF415314101020000000200000020DBF98EF7104341603BDF1FF415314138D6C585F710434160204191F415314101020000000200000038D6C585F710434160204191F4153141107A3663F7104341305C8F32F6153141010200000002000000107A3663F7104341305C8F32F615314188EB5198F7104341F0B7AF43F615314101020000000200000028E48396F710434190B0E159F615314188EB5198F7104341F0B7AF43F6153141010200000002000000B0EA73ADF8104341E00B93C9F815314140AD69F6F3104341B047E16AF715314101020000000200000040AD69F6F3104341B047E16AF7153141A03C2C0CF410434160B1BFBCF6153141010200000002000000A03C2C0CF410434160B1BFBCF615314150840D07F1104341A0703DBAF515314101020000000200000050840D07F1104341A0703DBAF515314120DBF94EF1104341D0E53F34F2153141'

line = wkb.loads(wkb_str, hex=True)

polys = list(sp_ops.polygonize(line))

print(len(polys)) # -> 0
```

Why is there nothing in the result?

The `line` is as follow:

[image]

I'm expecting a polygon with the same shape.

I guess it's because of this piece of line (close-up):

[image]

There seems to be no particular option for the polygonize function, unless I missed something.

Does anybody know a more robust way to polygonize such kind of line features in Python?

#### EDIT

Taras originally suggested in the comments below to give [`polygonize_full`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize_full) a try:

```py
geoms = list(sp_ops.polygonize_full(line))
for geom in geoms:
    print(f"type of geom is: {type(geom)}")
    print(f"is geom valid? {geom.is_valid}")
    print(f"is geom simple? {geom.is_simple}")
    print(f"is geom empty? {geom.is_empty}")
```

which results in:

```py
type of geom is: <class 'shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection'>
is geom valid? True
is geom simple? True
is geom empty? True
type of geom is: <class 'shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection'>
is geom valid? True
is geom simple? True
is geom empty? True
type of geom is: <class 'shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection'>
is geom valid? True
is geom simple? True
is geom empty? False
type of geom is: <class 'shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection'>
is geom valid? True
is geom simple? True
is geom empty? True
```

so it seems there is only `geoms[2]` which holds some information:

```py
geom[2].geoms

>: <shapely.geometry.base.HeterogeneousGeometrySequence at 0x7f42bd2c79a0>
```

But it's only of bunch of line pieces:

```py
list(geom[2].geoms)

>:
[<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c4eb0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c6ce0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c61d0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c79d0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c4c70>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c5a50>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c6f80>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c6320>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c61a0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c6950>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c6c80>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c6380>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c5c60>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c4be0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c4940>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c5ff0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c5300>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c4730>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c74c0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c65c0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c6770>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c58d0>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7f42bd2c7610>]
```

still no polygon.

Comment: But your original lines also include that dangle, is not it?

Comment: Yes it does; original data is provided as WKB in the code snippet for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there are three dangles ("edges which have one or both ends which are not incident on another edge endpoint") and a gap in your geometry and `polygonize` or `polygonize_full` will not introduce new edges.

Note that [polygonize_full(lines)](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize_full) don't detect them ([When does Shapely's "polygonize_full" detect a dangle?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244726/when-does-shapelys-polygonize-full-detect-a-dangle)):

```
result, dangles, cuts, invalids = polygonize_full(line)
print(dangles)
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

But using a solution adapted from the original script [ch09-04_locate_dangles.py](https://github.com/mdiener21/python-geospatial-analysis-cookbook/blob/master/ch09/code/ch09-04_locate_dangles.py) of the book [Python Geospatial Analysis Cookbook (Michael Diener)](https://www.packtpub.com/product/python-geospatial-analysis-cookbook/9781783555079) ([*A LineString must not have dangles*](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781783555079/9/ch09lvl1sec67/a-linestring-must-not-have-dangles)), it found the dangles.

```
lines =  [line for line in line]
for i, line in enumerate(lines):  
    # go through each line added first to second
    # then second to third and so on
    shply_lines = lines[:i] + lines[i+1:]
    # 0 is start point and -1 is end point
    # run through
    for start_end in [0, -1]:
        # convert line to point
        node = Point(line.coords[start_end])
        # replace touch in the original script to avoid floating point problems
        if any(node.distance(next_line) == 0.0 for next_line in shply_lines):
            continue
        else:
            print(node, line)


POINT (2499057.354699999 1119736.7896) LINESTRING (2499056.415100001 1119742.467500001, 2499057.354699999 1119736.7896)
POINT (2499055.175900001 1119734.3511) LINESTRING (2499055.175900001 1119734.351100001, 2499055.190000001 1119734.264400002)
POINT (2499057.355099998 1119736.7874) LINESTRING (2499057.355099998 1119736.7874, 2499047.925099999 1119735.4175)
```

[image]

First

[image]

Second, third and the gap:

[image]

You need to eliminate this gap to polygonize your geometry

[image]

Comment: Can you recommend that book, or maybe something better exist in your opinion ? :)

Comment: Thanks for the precious hint. I didn't even noticed the gap! Notice: `ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the 'geoms' property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry. 
  lines =  [l for l in line]` -> it should be: `lines = [l for l in line.geoms]`. In addition, do you have any advice on a tool or whatever solution to "automatically" (tolerance based) fix the dangles/gaps? Maybe a triangulation based solution can close the gaps, but it won't remove the dangles...

Comment: Actually, I think it will be hard to conjugate both a destructive process (removing the dangles) and a constructive one (closing the gaps) in one tool...

Comment: You can try to use [momepy close_gaps or extend_lines](https://github.com/pysal/momepy/blob/main/docs/user_guide/preprocessing/simple_preprocessing.ipynb)